# What Project marked for deletion error means while working with Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

I access Fusion Tables thru its API. Recently, I've started to get the following error (it worked well before):

> HttpError 403 when requesting
>   https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?alt=json&sql=SELECT+COUNT%28%29+FROM+my-table-id
>   returned "Project marked for deletion."

What does it mean? Which project is marked for deletion? I've checked my project settings at Google Developers Console (https://console.developers.google.com/project/my-project-id/settings) and it is not marked for deletion.

Comment: This is coming from the Fusion Tables API stack somewhere, so it's not related to your project. We're looking into what's causing it but we don't have an answer yet.

Comment: @RodMcChesney, thanks for the answer. Please let me know if any details (like project id) are required to help you with the investigation.

Comment: Yes, please: can you send a mail to googletables-feedback@google.com with the relevant info about your project?